# File upload from desktop application to google drive in .net 3.5 framework

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I would like to upload a zip file from a desktop application to google drive.
I got pointers in your site but it was using .net framework 4 and above. The limitation is the desktop application is supported for .net framework 3.5 only. 
I have been able to do the authorization part , but could not proceed with file upload. Need help.
Thanks !

Comment: Post the .net 4 specific code that doesn't work with .net 3.5, we can't guess what your problem is.

Comment: @BenRobinson, I was trying the code available here (http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/) . It works with 4.0 and upwards.  I am new to .net domain , and also trying to use google SDK APIs first time . Appreciate your help.